Using a function pointer inside a struct
I am trying to use a struct as a function container, but I am unable to do so.
Here is my code for the struct aliased as methods
typedef struct {
        void (*addAtHead)(LinkedList*,int);
        void (*addAtTail)(LinkedList*,int);
        void (*remFromHead)(LinkedList*);
        void (*remFromTail)(LinkedList*);
}methods;

And here I am pointing the methods's pointers to corresponding functions
methods LinkedListF;
LinkedListF.addAtHead = addAtH;
LinkedListF.addAtTail = addAtT;
LinkedListF.remFromHead = remFromH;
LinkedListF.remFromTail = remFromT;

It was expected that the LinkedListF.addAtHead(LinkedList *l,int value) function call will call  addAtH, but during compilation, it gives
LinkedList.c:43:12: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
   43 | LinkedListF.addAtHead = addAtH;
....and more errors

I have verified that there are no missing semicolons or other mistakes, also if I try with the following code, it correctly compiles
methods LinkedListF = {addAtH,addAtT,remFromH,remFromT};

Can somebody please explain where I am doing wrong?

[Edit] your question with a [mcve].

LinkedListF.addAtHead(LinkedList *l,int value) is not a function call. LinkedListF.addAtHead(&list,42) is a function call.

Tip: To me, methods LinkedListF; is very confusing. I would expect the type to use have the uppercase letters, and I would expect the var to be all lowercase (Methods linked_list;).

@Stephen Newell, I approved the Question from the Staging Ground because the code they provided is all that's needed to reproduce the problem, (although adding typedef struct { int x; } LinkedList; makes it clearer).

Unrelated to the problem, you should make it a habit of always using typedef when working with function pointers. That is typedef void AddAtHead_t(LinkedList*,int); then AddAtHead_t* addAtHead;.

@ikegami - I assumed this was like so many question where some random part of a function was copy/pasted.  Didn't occur to me that the asker was trying to set member variables outside a function.

@Stephen Newell, yeah, I know. And you're not the only one. Trying to avoid having the question closed for insufficient details. (Probably a dupe out there, though.)

It's quite probable that your error is outisde the snippet of code you have pasted.  As you have been suggested, post a complete example, so the declarations can be properly isolated from the context.

You have the following outside of a function:
methods LinkedListF;
LinkedListF.addAtHead = addAtH;
LinkedListF.addAtTail = addAtT;
LinkedListF.remFromHead = remFromH;
LinkedListF.remFromTail = remFromT;

Only declarations are allowed outside of functions. The last four of those lines are not declarations but expression statements which can only be found inside functions.
This works inside of a function.
The desired effect can also be obtained by using a declaration with an initializer.
methods LinkedListF = { addAtH, addAtT, remFromH, remFromT };

methods LinkedListF = {
   .addAtHead   = addAtH,
   .addAtTail   = addAtT,
   .remFromHead = remFromH,
   .remFromTail = remFromT,
};

These work inside or outside of a function.
Both the failing approach and the working approaches use =, but = inside a declaration denotes an initializer instead of an assignment.

Perhaps show how to initialize it with an initializer?

@Ian Abbott, That's already in the question

So it is. I missed that bit! Still, it could be improved with designated initializers.

@Ian Abbott, Added.
